# Find all entries where one of attributes within array is empty

Tags: mongodb

I've following mongodb query:

```
db
.getCollection("entries")
.find({
    $and: [
      {
        "array.attribute_1": {
          $exists: true,
          $not: {
            $size: 0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        $or: [
          { "array.attribute_2": { $exists: true, $size: 0 } },
          { "array.attribute_2": { $exists: true, $eq: {} } }
        ]
      },
    ]
})
```

And example of my document:

```
{
    _id: 'foo',
    array: [
       {attribute_1: [], attribute_2: []}, 
       {attribute_1: ['bar'], attribute_2: []}
    ]
}
```

In my understanding my query should find all `entries` that have **at least one** element within `array` that has existent and not empty `attribute_1` and existent empty array or empty object `attribute_2`. However, this query finds all `entries` that has **all** elements within `array` that has existent and not empty `attribute_1` and existent empty array or empty object `attribute_2`. As such, my `foo` entry won't be found.

What should be the correct formula for my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$find` would find the first document with the matching criteria and in your case that first document contains all the arrays. You either need to use `$project` with `$filter` or aggregation with `$unwind` and `$match`.

Something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$array" },
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { "array.attribute_1.0": { $exists: true }},
        {
          $or: [
            { "array.attribute_2.0": { $exists: false } },
            { "array.attribute_2.0": { $eq: {} } }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

You can see it working [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/UJ3ZJNY7F58)

Also since you are trying to find out if array is empty and exists at the same time using `.0` with `$exists` is a quick and one statement way to get the same result as with both `$exists` and `$size`.

Comment: The `.0` unfortunately doesn't work, as `attribute_2` can be an object, **but** thank you for bringing up `$unwind` to my attention as it's exactly what was needed